# Hover in jquery not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I have a question with 2 radio buttons and I want when someone hovers the mouse over a radio button then the background color of question text gets changed and there should be an alert.

Below is the code I am using however it is not working, please suggest on mistake and help correcting it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#q11_1").hover()(
                    function(){
                    alert("in");
                    $(div).css("background-color",'yellow');
                    },
                    function(){
                    alert("out");
                    }
                );
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>Please select the type of link below.</div>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="link" id="q11_1">Common<br>
        <input type="radio" name="link" id="q11_2">Individual
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First step: Press F12 and check console. Any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error. Change the code like this

```
$('#q11_1').hover(function() {
        alert("in");
        $("div").css("background-color", 'yellow');
    },
    function() {
        alert("out");
    }
);
```

Note that you binded hover for radio only(not for the text)

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/432/)